# No member named 'getMat' in 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer'

Tags: objective-c++, opencv3.0

```
@interface FJFaceRecognizer () {
    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> _faceClassifier;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *labelsDictionary;

@end

@implementation FJFaceRecognizer

    - (NSArray *)labels {
```

On next line I get error message `No member named 'getMat' in 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer'`, when using OpenCV 3.0:

```
        cv::Mat labels = _faceClassifier->getMat("labels");

        if (labels.total() == 0) {
            return @[];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (MatConstIterator_<int> itr = labels.begin<int>(); itr != labels.end<int>(); ++itr ) {
                int lbl = *itr;
                [mutableArray addObject:@(lbl)];
            }
            return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
        }
    }
}
```

What should I use instead of `getMat` in OpenCV 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `std::vector<int>` of labels, you should be able to use `getLabelsByString`

http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html

Might be worth looking over the transition guide going from 2 to 3

http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html